# SignalR TypeLoadException Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.IHubProxy

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I am getting the following exception when calling a method in a self-host scenario using SignalR 2.0.1.

The service appears to be using the correct Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll, no reference was installed to the GAC.

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.IHubProxy' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Also, I've got 2.0.1 source from GitHub and the interface is definitely present.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like a day or two of rest to discover the problem.

Previously I tried everything to see what was going on, from dropping all references, reinstalling packages from Nuget, not using Nuget, adding binding redirects to the application config, and even running fuslogvw.exe to verify DLL bindings.

Then it occurred to me the error was happening not in the service application, but in another project being referenced.

So this was clumsy, just hadn't updated the reference to Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll in all projects.